# Type Could Not Be Resolved Error

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos

I'm a newbie to C++ and here I got one stupid question.

utility.h:

```
#ifndef UTILITY_H_
#define UTILITY_H_

 using namespace std;

#include <iostream>

enum Error_code {success, fail, range_error, underflow, overflow, fatal,
          not_present, duplicate_error, entry_inserted, entry_found,
                internal_error};


#endif /* UTILITY_H_ */
```

Stack.h:

```
#ifndef STACK_H_
#define STACK_H_

#include "utility.h"

typedef double Stack_entry;

class Stack {
public:
    Stack();
    ~Stack();
    bool empty();
    Error_code push(const Stack_entry &item);


#endif /* STACK_H_ */
```

These two header files are the only files in my project right now, and they're in the same folder. However, the Error_code in the Stack.h is always reported to be "Type could not be resolved". BTW, I'm using Eclipse on Mac Os X, and I've installed CDT.

Is there anyone has idea about this error or has been experiencing this? Thanks!

---

Sorry that I forgot to paste the header file for the Node, but it has the same problem with Error_code. Now I've removed that part.Here's the error message (sorry I'm not allowed to post image):

Description: Type 'Error_code' could not be resolved

Resource: Stack.h
Path: /StackImplementation/header
Location: line 21
Type: Semantic Error

Also I forgot to mention that these two file can be compiled by g++ command, but Eclipse always report the type error.

---

Wierd...somehow I recreated the project and the error disappeared.. Thanks all guys!

Comment: Note that both littleadv and I were _guessing_ about the problem at hand -- without the full error message, that's our best shot. Give full error messages from compilers in the future, please :)

Comment: I've paste the error message, hope it will help. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

Where is the `Node` type declared?

```
protected:
    Node *top_node;
```

Comment: I just tried out his code with GCC 4.6, and the only error I get is that `Node` is not a type - no complaints about `Error_code`.

Comment: ... which just goes to show why it is important to always show the entire error message from compilers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Nit ~ "Node" isn't defined in this chain? Depending on your tools, that could be obfuscating your answer. Everything else seems fine. Even stubbed out a .cc to test it out ~

```
#include "stack.h"

bool Stack::empty() {
    return true;
}

Error_code Stack::push(const Stack_entry &item) {
    return success;
}
```

Maybe you can see something wrong in your .cc besides Node not being defined?